# CodeIgniter - error trying to view uploaded pdf files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having difficulty trying to view a pdf file outside of the webroot folder.

This is the view file - I'm grabbing the file id from the URL and then querying the db to get all the file info stored from the upload.

```
     $fid = $_GET['fid'];
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE FID = $fid");
    $fileinfo = $query->result();
    foreach ($fileinfo as $row)
    {


    $fname = $row->file_name;
    $ftype =  $row->file_type;
    $fpath =  $row->file_path;
    $full_path = $row->full_path;
    $raw_name = $row->raw_name;
    $client_name = $row->client_name;
    $file_ext = $row->file_ext;
    $file_size =  $row->file_size;
    $is_image = $row->is_image;
    $width =  $row->image_width;
    $height = $row->image_height;
    $img_type =  $row->image_type;
    $img_size =  $row->image_size_str;
    $orig_name = $row->orig_name;
    $created =  $row->created;

    }
```

Then I'm taking that info and passing it to the File_viewer_model using the following:

```
    $this->load->model('File_viewer_model');

    $this->File_viewer_model->getFileInfo($fname,$ftype);
```

The function in the model that receives the data is as follows:

```
function getFileInfo($fname,$ftype){


   $path = '/home/sitename/uploads/' . $fname;


header('Content-Type: ' . $ftype);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));

readfile($path);

        }
```

The problem is when I click on the link to open a new tab and try to display the file, I get the following error:

> File does not begin with '%PDF-'.

The file is in a 777 permissions directory called uploads right outside of the webroot - I've been all over the web and there seems to be several methods to display a pdf file, none of which seem to work for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the issue isn't with the file but rather the browser rendering of it. http://file-repair.blogspot.ca/2012/01/how-to-solve-pdf-file-error-message.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The problem was I was passing a header_view page in the controller before the `$this->load->view('file_viewer_view');` section.

The PDF viewer was trying to parse the header_view first before the `header('Content-Type: application/pdf')` code in the file_viewer_view and thus generating the error.

I removed everything from the controller before the `$this->load->view('file_viewer_view');` and it works like a champ!

Hopefully, this will save someone several hours of banging your head against the wall like I experienced!